# Random variate from R distribution does not fit expected distribution in Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, rlink

I am learning the ropes with `` RLink` `` and am getting an odd result from some of the functions in the R *actuar* package.

```
Needs["RLink`"];
InstallR[];
REvaluate["install.packages('actuar')"];
REvaluate["library('actuar')"];
```

I setup a function to the Pareto random variate function in R to process its results in Mathematica. The reverse of `shape` and `scale` is needed as the parameter order is different between the two.

```
rPareto = RFunction["function(num, shp, scl) rpareto(num, shp, scl) "];
obs = 1000; shape = .5; scale = 4;
rp = rPareto[obs, shape, scale];
mp = RandomVariate[ParetoDistribution[scale, shape], obs];
```

I then check observations follow the expected distribution.

```
FindDistributionParameters[#, ParetoDistribution[k, α]] & /@ {rp, mp}
```

> ```
> {{k -> 0.000198107, α -> 0.0877986}, {k -> 4.00161, α -> 0.501952}}
> ```

```
DistributionFitTest[#, ParetoDistribution[scale, shape]] & /@ {rp, mp}
```

> ```
> {1.11022*10^-16, 0.77595}
> ```

The result from R appears to be way off the mark with 1,000 observations used. The parameters for the R result is way off and the p-value shows the null should definitely be rejected.

I think it is most likely that I missed a step because the R result is way too off for this not to have been noticed by the many users of R. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Mma 11.1 Win 7 Ent

R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)

actuar version 1.1-6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `actuar` help in ***R***:

> The Pareto distribution with parameters shape = a and scale = s has
>   density:    f (x) = a s^a/(x + s)^(a + 1)

*Mathematica* uses a different definition:

> a^s s x^(-1 - s)

You note that the parameters are "reversed" but also ***R*** uses `x+s` in the denominator and *Mathematica* just uses `x`.

To generate random samples in *Mathematica* from the same probability density function in ***R*** you would need to use

```
mp = RandomVariate[ParetoDistribution[scale, shape, 0], obs];
```

and perform the fit with

```
FindDistributionParameters[#, ParetoDistribution[k, α, 0]] & /@ {rp, mp}
```

Comment: So this R package is using type II with mu = 0.  Great detective work. (+1)